# Dynamically created hidden inputs not appearing on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

On one of my webpages users can add a row to a table in the place of a placeholder. The html for the row that is added contains a number of hidden input fields. On all desktop browsers this works fine but but on my iPad (and possibly other mobile devices) The hidden inputs are not being added to the page and consequently missing when I view the source code.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening and what can be done about it? Thanks for your help.

FYI

The html that gets added to the page is stored in a javascript variable and is something like this.

```
new_row_html = '<tr>';
new_row_html += '<td>Cell 1</td>';
new_row_html += '<td>Cell 2</td>';
new_row_html += "</tr>";
new_row_html += '<input id="hid_1_id" name="hid_1" type="hidden" value="" />';
new_row_html += '<input id="hid_2_id" name="hid_2" type="hidden" value="" />';
```

I then use jQuery's replaceWith() method to replace the place holder with the new html

Comment: Try adding the `<input>`s outside of the table, or inside of a table cell, rather than between the rows -- what you're doing is invalid HTML and may be filtered out by certain browsers.

Comment: Have you successfully created hidden inputs in HTML manually (not dynamic in the same place as your code would create them dynamically?  Just to determine if this is a problem with the placement of the tags rather than an issue with your JS.

Comment: Blazemonger was right. I moved the hidden inputs into the last table cell and now everything is working as it should be. A bit of a schoolboy error on my part but thank you both for your help. If you want to add what you said as an answer rather than a comment I can give it a green tick.